# On Click - get button pressed?

Tags: jquery

I have delete buttons that are added to the page dynamically.

I use this, for when delete is pressed:

```
 $('#gallery').on('click', '.btn-delete', function(){

 });
```

But how can I get the instance of the delete button pressed inside the on fnc? I've tried this, but no luck:

```
$(this).addClass('btn-danger');
```

Comment: That should work, what's happening?

Comment: Anything in console? Post your HTML too.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/G46c4/

Comment: Could you paste your complete code

Comment: Hmm it appears that its failing to override my css on btn-delete. I have background: black. How can I get it to override it?

Comment: I think your issue is that the `.btn-danger` isn't overriding `.btn-delete?`

Comment: @MackieeE yep. How can I get it to override it?

Comment: Either remove it then add it, or toggle class (or if you're naughty, add `!important` :) .. )

Comment: css rule specificity is a completely different topic.

Comment: But I cant remove it, it will screw up the style of the btn

Comment: If it's a simple class, it should override it fine. The rule for `.btn-delete` must be more specific.

Comment: Well, it won't screw up the style of the button as long as you have `.btn` included

Comment: Yes it will. I have additional styles in my css

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery delegate

```
$('#gallery').delegate('.btn-delete', 'click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
});
```

But as far as I know it's equivalent for on event..